# GSA: microdata gets truncated

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-search-appliance

I'm feeding the data of into Google Search Appliance. My feed contains HTML documents enchanced with Microdata from schema.org (specifically [this](http://schema.org/Product)).

To my surprise:

1. the search results aren't any different to the ones I receive without microdata enhancement in place,
2. while using test tool, I'm seeing that GSA cuts the Microdata from the markup.

**Questions**:

1. How to improve GSA search results?
2. Why would GSA cut the Microdata from the markup? Should I be concerned about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GSA does not support those microdata.
It typically only supports meta tags under the format `<meta name="category" content="computer"/>`

Comment: Jérôme, is there any other way to let GSA about the semantics of data? Will it take into account the meta tags once establishing rank for a page?

Comment: It doesn't specifically use meta tags to establish the rank of the page. But when you do a search, if the term of the search match something stored in a meta tag, this might slightly influence the result. You can also decide to use Biasing Profiles to establish specific rules (ie: if metatag=="Books", boost  the record up)